# calculate acceleration given speed

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science, physics

Sorry if this seems like a stupid question,
I have a dataset which looks like this

```
type    time    latitude    longitude   altitude (m)    speed (km/h)    name    desc    currentdistance timeelapsed
T   2017-10-07 10:44:48 28.750766667    77.088805000    783.5   0.0 2017-10-07_10-44-48     0.0 00:00:00
T   2017-10-07 10:44:58 28.752345000    77.087840000    853.5   7.8         198.70532   00:00:10
T   2017-10-07 10:45:00 28.752501667    77.087705000    854.5   7.7         220.53915   00:00:12
```

Im not exactly sure how to approach this,calculating acceleration requires taking difference of speed and time,any suggestions on what i may try?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want acceleration formola?

Comment: Ive posted the forumala in the question,the thing is when i try taking the difference of time i get it cannot be interpreted as an integer,so im kinda looking for an approach i could try

Comment: let me confirm your confusion, you are confused because acceleration are data that exists between those records, right?

Comment: you should convert your data to normat datatime format. ( because your data is a human_readble format )

Comment: accel = (vEnd - vStart) / time. For your first calculation  time would be 58 - 48 = 10 secs, vEnd = 853.5 vStart = 783,5

Comment: convert the time to seconds

Comment: @am05mhz acceleration can be calculated given the above data ,it isnt given specifically, ill may be try converting it to seconds

Comment: Convert the time to a delta from the previous row. Then its easy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your data was loaded from a CSV as follows:

```
type,time,latitude,longitude,altitude (m),speed (km/h),name,desc,currentdistance,timeelapsed
T,2017-10-07 10:44:48,28.750766667,77.088805000,783.5,0.0,2017-10-07_10-44-48,,0.0,00:00:00
T,2017-10-07 10:44:58,28.752345000,77.087840000,853.5,7.8,,,198.70532,00:00:10
T,2017-10-07 10:45:00,28.752501667,77.087705000,854.5,7.7,,,220.53915,00:00:12
```

The `time` column is converted to a `datetime` object, and the `timeelapsed` column is converted into seconds. From this you could add an `acceleration` column by
calculating the difference in `speed (km/h)` between each row and dividing by the difference in `time` between each row as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime    
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', parse_dates=['time'], dtype={'name':str, 'desc':str})
df['timeelapsed'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['timeelapsed'], format='%H:%M:%S') - datetime(1900, 1, 1)).dt.total_seconds()
df['acceleration'] = (df['speed (km/h)'] - df['speed (km/h)'].shift(1)) / (df['timeelapsed'] - df['timeelapsed'].shift(1))

print df
```

Giving you:

```
  type                time   latitude  longitude  altitude (m)  speed (km/h)                 name desc  currentdistance  timeelapsed  acceleration
0    T 2017-10-07 10:44:48  28.750767  77.088805         783.5           0.0  2017-10-07_10-44-48  NaN          0.00000          0.0           NaN
1    T 2017-10-07 10:44:58  28.752345  77.087840         853.5           7.8                  NaN  NaN        198.70532         10.0          0.78
2    T 2017-10-07 10:45:00  28.752502  77.087705         854.5           7.7                  NaN  NaN        220.53915         12.0         -0.05
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Ryan I understand what you've done, I'm a bit confused because here you output acceleration as a scalar, when it is a vector quantity.